# How WiFi advertising work?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, advertisements

There are some router-like devices like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPgnaiGYgmQ which push advertisements when the user connects to the wireless network. How these and the other "like our page to continue" work? Are there any python implementations or something to have a look at?

Thank you.

Comment: It's called a captive portal...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

The WiFi server (ala the product in your video link) controls your device's traffic to and from the network, so it's able to intercept and redirect all requests (to an ad, or a EULA-like page, etc.), until a flag is thrown (users agreed to the EULA, or liked a page, or watched an ad to completion, etc.)

> Are there any python implementations or something to have a look at?

Perhaps, but SU is not the place to ask for product recommendations (it's specifically off-topic).  Now that you know what's its called (in general) that will hopefully get you looking in the right places to find one.